# Why is my PHP / MySQL inserting instead of updating?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, sql-update

```
if ($Funct == "BUILD" AND $Mode == "GROUND")
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $landCon WHERE North = '" . $North . "' AND West = '" . $West ."'" ;
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error occurred in [$sql]: " . mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    If ($Count == 0 )
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $landCon (West,North,Type1) VALUES ($West,$North,'$Char')";
        mysql_query($sql) or die("Error occurred in RootA as:[$sql]: " . mysql_error());

    }
    else
    {
        $result=mysql_query("UPDATE $landCon SET Type1= '$Char' WHERE North = $North AND West=$West") or die( "Database Error: ".mysql_error());
    }
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
```

Instead of it updating where an entry exists it is inserting. My intention is to have it update if there is already the specified `$North` and `$South` entry so that there is only one North/South value per map grid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

If ($Count == 0 )
```

Is `$count` `$Count` ?

captcha: languages that silently initialize new variables when you make a typo

Comment: Thank you! i guess i stared at it too long.